# full toolbar in django-ckeditor-5

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, ckeditor5, django-ckeditor

i cant use full toolbar in django-ckeditor-5

in ckeditor-4 use:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
    },
}
```

But in version 5, this method does not work
please help me
please help me
please help me
please help me
please help me
thank you